# prettyphoto alt displayed when picture is loaded

Tags: html, image, prettyphoto, alt

I'm using prettyphoto for the first time, very nice tool. I would like to know if more people have this problem. Its not crucial but I hate to not do things because I dont understand them.  This is the code:

```
<div class="single_left">
    <a href="_img/examples/image-1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gal1]" title="it works"><img src="_img/examples/thumb-1_50.jpg" alt="WHATEVER INFO" /></a>
</div>
```

It works perfectly. But I have a doubt. If you look all the code you will see that its quite simpel. Its a div in which inside there is a `<a>` and inside there is a `<img>` thats acts as a thumbnail. As any for any `<img>` you need to add an alt="" atribute. The idea of this atribute is that if somebody has slow internet or if the image fails to load, a small description would be displayed in a text format, this will be the content of alt="". In this case "WHATEVER INFO" (Check code above). So if the image is displayed this alternative text shoud NOT be displayed.

ok... clear

The issue is that with prettyphoto if the picture is zoomed from a click you can see the alt="" text on top of the frame of prettyphoto. So in this case WHATEVER INFO would be displayed. This is not its purpose and of course breaks any design plan.

Does anybody know why this happens??

Is there a way of solving this so I can put some alternative text??

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/hide-title-and-alt-text-on-pretty-photo-gallery-images), add this CSS code to `css/custom.css` to do what you want:

```
div.ppt, .pp_description {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a custom.css file?! They talk about it as it exists but in the original download there is no such CSS file. I imagine that they created a custom.css file. Is this correct?! If display none its the same as not inserting any alt value right? Therefore no point on writing any text for SEO purposes. Is right whay I say?

Answer (score 0):

I can let you know that the answer to my question os exactly like this:

```
div.ppt {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This will make the alt value not displayed.

What I don;t know is if the picture is not loaded if the alt will work as such... At least you know how to take it out.

Greetings!!